# Enable to connect oracle database with asp.net windows service

Tags: asp.net, oracle, windows-services

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=MyOracleDB;User Id=user;Password=****;" name="con"/>   
  </connectionStrings>
```

This is my connection string. i am using visual studio 2013 and oracle 10g version.

This is my code.

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);
        public DataTable GetTday()
        {
            conn.Open();
            string query = "select * from tday";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();
            return dt;          
        }
```

it shows 'ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified' this error. please someone help

Comment: Can you connect with other tools like SQL*Plus or can you reach the DB by `tnsping MyOracleDB`?

Comment: it is working fine with other tools.problem getting in oracle only

Comment: Did you define `TNS_ADMIN` Environment variable? Did you set value in Registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\TNS_ADMIN`?

Comment: No, How to do it?? please help

Comment: See https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm - or do you know google?